# Does yeast grow on LB agar plates?

Tags: yeast, growth-media

I would like to grow E coli cells on cellophane on top of LB plate, and then grow yeast cells on the same LB plate. Does (or how well) yeast grow on LB plates? Is there a composition media that can be good for both E. coli and yeast? Has anyone done this experiment?

Comment: not sure if LB is a good medium but yeast does contaminate bacterial plates often. Fungi also grow easily. May not be the most optimal medium but nonetheless fungi seem to be quite robust.

Answer (score 3):

Not well, they need  dextrose. Use YBT:

20 g Casein Peptone Tpe-M
10 g Yeast Extract
20 g Dextrose
17 g Agar

q.s. to 975 mls in di-water.

pH to 6.2 w 5M NaOH

q.s. to 1L with di-water.

Autoclave for 45 min at 121C

Aseptically dispense in Petri dishes.

Store at 4C for up to 12 weeks.

If you want to grow Co-culture do so in LB supplemented with 20g/L Dex.